# Почему браузер вообще ничего не показывает?

Tags: php

Ребят, объясните, в чём проблема, не могу понять. Браузер вообще ничего не показывает.

```
<?php
include('config.php');
?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit_admin']) {
    if ($admin['login'] == $_POST['login'] || $admin['password'] == $_POST['password']) {
        session_start();
        $admin                  = $_POST['login'];
        $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $admin;

        //Если перешол по ссылки Добавить новость то открываем форму
        if (isset($_GET['am']) AND $_GET['am'] == 'addnews') {
            //Если форма отправлена начинаем обрабатывать её
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if ($_POST['title'] == '') {
                    echo 'Вы не ввели Заголовок';

                } elseif ($_POST['desc'] == '') {
                    echo 'Вы не ввели текст новости';

                } else {
                    $title = trim($_POST['title']); //Убераем пробелы в начале и в конце
                    $desc  = trim($_POST['desc']); //Убераем пробелы в начале и в конце
                    //Соединение с базой данных
                    $link = mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
                    //Выбор базы данных 
                    mysql_select_db("$db") or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных' . mysql_error());
                    $sql = $sql = ("INSERT INTO news (`title`,`desc`)VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $desc . "')");
                    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    if ($query) {
                        echo 'новость добавлена <a href="admin.php">Назад</a> ';

                    } else {
                        echo 'Новость не добавлена';
                    }
                }
            } else {
?>

<form method="POST" action="admin.php?am=addnews">
    <p><b>Добавление новости на сайт:</b></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="title"></p>
    <p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="desc"></textarea></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>

<?

            }
        } else {
            echo '<a href="admin.php?am=addnews">добавить новость</a>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Вы не верно ввели логин или пароль';
    }
} else {
?>

<form method="POST" action="admin.php">
<p><b>Введите Логин и Пароль:</b></p>
<p><input type="text" name="login"></p>
<p><input type="password" name="password"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit_admin"  value="Войти"></p>
</form>

<?
}
?>
```

Comment: В коде ошибки и они не отображаются либо вы не тот url открываете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка 7 - потеряна скоба

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_admin'])**)**{
```

Больше ошибок синтаксиса не вижу.

Comment: А больше и ненадо ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 include('config.php');
 ?>

<? } ?>
```

Зачем это? Сделайте всё в одном бегин-енде.